# Saving 1 million records to core data taking so much time

Tags: ios, core-data, objective-c-blocks

I am saving 1 million records from CSV to the core database. It takes near about 35min to save all the records.Is there anyway to reduce the insertion time. Here is the my code which i used to insert the records :

```
 NSString *resourceFileName = @"npidata_20140209_reduced2";
NSString *pathToFile =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: resourceFileName ofType: @"csv"];

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
__block int count = 0;
```

[content enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString *line, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"LINE==%@",line);

```
    NSArray *lineComponents=[line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if(lineComponents){       
            float f=[[lineComponents objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
            NSString *strNPI=[lineComponents objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *strProviderLastName=[lineComponents objectAtIndex:1];
            NSString *strProviderFirstName=[lineComponents objectAtIndex:2];
            NSString *strLicenseNumber=[lineComponents objectAtIndex:6];
            NSString *strLicenseState=[lineComponents objectAtIndex:7];         
            NSManagedObject *object=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AttendeeInformation" inManagedObjectContext:[DataBaseManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext];

            NSString *strFullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",strProviderFirstName,strProviderLastName];

            [object setValue:strNPI forKey:@"npiNumber"];
            [object setValue:strProviderFirstName forKey:@"attendeeFirstName"];
            [object setValue:strProviderLastName forKey:@"attendeeLastName"];
            [object setValue:strFullName forKey:@"attendeeName"];
            [object setValue:strLicenseNumber forKey:@"licnesedNumber"];
            [object setValue:strLicenseState forKey:@"stateLicense"];

            NSError *error;
            count++;
            if(count%100==0)
            {
                if (![[DataBaseManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext save:&error])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                [[DataBaseManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:YES];
            }
        if (count==lineComponents.count)
        {
            completionHandler();
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: read this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1

Comment: Change '10 Lakh' in your question to '1 million'. This will make it easier for people from all around the world to understand. The word 'lakh' is only used in India.

Comment: You are saving your context way too much.

Comment: Also, are you sure you have a SQLite store? I've accidentally used XML stores by accident several times. The Xcode template uses XML, I think.

Comment: Not sure, but here's one thing: `NSLog` takes a **lot** more time than you probably think. 1 million `NSLog` calls will have a significant effect on overall speed.

Comment: @DrewMcCormack...... yes i have SQLite store.....

Comment: @TomHarrington.......I commented all the logs before run on the device....

Answer (score 3):

You should run Instruments with Time Profile and Core Data to see what your bottlenecks are. It's the best way to validate your performance issues. Core Data might or might not be your problem.

Comment: I also used this instruments to check the saving time of the records but there it works fine...Every save takes some miliseconds to save the records....

Comment: Do you mean "there it works fine" in that the total time it takes is more reasonable than 30+ minutes? Or do you mean just the individual saves to the database? You should be able to tell with Time Profile which line of code you are spending the most time. If you post a screenshot of your run, that would be useful.

Comment: i mean when i used instruments and checking the time for saving every records then its saving time is in milliseconds for every record.

Answer (score 2):

@Desdenova had it right. You need to get all the records in your context and save the context once at the end, or at least in very large batches. Under the API, sqlite is doing a separate transaction for each context save which is very expensive. If you do all the operations as a single transaction it's orders of magnitude faster. Do a test run where you comment out:

```
            if (![[DataBaseManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext save:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
```

and add these same 3 lines after the loop.